# Talend Open Studio Big Data error while creating Project

Tags: java, hadoop, talend

I installed Talend Open studio for Big Data 6.0 and while creating project below error pops up. I have Java installed and version is 1.7.0_65.Please let me know if any thing need to be fixed.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.JavaRoutineSynchronizer.doSyncRoutine(JavaRoutineSynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.syncRoutine(AbstractRoutineSynchronizer.java:169)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.JavaRoutineSynchronizer.syncRoutineItems(JavaRoutineSynchronizer.java:103)
    at org.talend.designer.codegen.JavaRoutineSynchronizer.syncAllRoutinesForLogOn(JavaRoutineSynchronizer.java:82)
    at org.talend.core.CoreService.syncAllRoutines(CoreService.java:281)
    at org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.logOnProject(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:1826)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginHelper$2.run(LoginHelper.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Comment: were you able to import existing dummy projects which come with studio?

Comment: No. I am getting same error after import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close Talend. Delete the folder **.m2** the folder is located in C:\Users\Administrator (if you are using Administrator account). Open Talend.
PS: You need to install jdk 8. jdk 7 is not supported for Talend 6.x